# Suppress iPad virtual keyboard input in version running on macOS?

Tags: xcode, macos, cordova, ipad

I've compiled my Cordova ios app for Mac, but there's an odd behaviour whenever the cursor goes into an input box. It looks like the app is trying to call up the virtual keyboard, but all that shows is an opaque bar that obscures my footer menu. Here's what the screen looks like without the input focus:

[image]

And as soon as I put the cursor in the input box, the grey bar on the bottom rises from the lowermost edge of the screen:

[image]

Xcode throws an error:

> 2023-07-30 11:10:05.834129+0200 I-Ching[36626:1668765] [RTILog]
> -[RTIInputSystemClient remoteTextInputSessionWithID:performInputOperation:]  Can only perform
> input operation for an active session. sessionID =
> 2C255827-6219-472F-A781-44017AE0F4BC

At first I thought it was one of the bootstrap navbars misbehaving, but I've inspected all of them with elements and it's something extraneous to my code, so I'm guessing from that and the error message above that it's some failure to resolve the normal iPad behaviour of bringing up the virtual keyboard.

Any suggestions how to identify and fix what's going on here?